# Correct way to copy vm disk

Tags: centos, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, migration, dd

I have a VM’s disk to copy from one host to another for live migration.

I can think of two ways to copy the VM’s disk.

1. Do a snapshot of the Logical Volume in the original host, create a Logical Volume in the destination host of the same size. Then copy using `dd` command.
2. Create a new VM in the destination Logical Volume, then do a snapshot of the Logical Volume from the original host and run `rsync` to copy all directories and files to the destination Logical Volume with `rsync` option `—delete`.

The first method takes longer as it duplicates the entire volume. The second method is less straightforward. What’s the best way to copy the disk?

Comment: Do you have shared storage across hosts where migration operation will take place ?

Comment: Then just `virsh migrate` it and be done.

Comment: 'virsh migrate --live guest03 qemu+ssh://73.94.23.2/system' gives an error "cannot open file '/dev/volumeGroup/guest03': No such file or directory"

Comment: I admit i don't know kvm as i am a vmware addict...but maybe this can help http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/kvm-clone.html

Comment: How can this be "live" migration if you are copying the disk image yourself?

Comment: Correction, I don't have shared storage.

Answer (score 2):

If you have shared storage, make sure the VM's disk is located on the shared storage, accessible by both hosts, and mounted in the same mountpoint. Then standard, libvirt-directed live migration will simply work.

If you don't have shared storage, KVM/QEMU supports that as well. In more ways than one, in fact [1]

It is, of course, a better idea to use `libvirt` [2]

[1] http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/LiveBlockMigration 
[2] http://libvirt.org/migration.html